# The distribution of visit times to the arc of absorbing DTMC

Tags: graph-theory, random-variables, markov-chains, markov-process, random-walk

Consider there is an absorbing DTMC $X_n$ and it has $m$ absorbing states and $n$ nonabsorbing states.

My question is if the $X_n$ starts from a transient state $s$ and ends in a specific absorbing state $t$, what is the distribution of the time $X_n$ visit arc $i-j$, $N_{s,ij,t}$? If we dont demand this $X_n$ ends in $t$, what is the distribution of $N_{s,ij}$?

I want to know the $Prob\left\{ N_{s,ij,t}>l \right\} $ and the $Mean\left\{ N_{s,ij,t} \right\} $, I found the $Mean\left\{ N_{s,ij,t} \right\} $ can be derived by absorbing DTMC with reward, but it can not give us any information of its distribution.

I thought there will be a classic conclusion of this problem, but I was astonished I did not find any conclusion or result of arcs from Markov textbook. I will be very glad if there is anyone can give me any references or the result of this problem.

Comment: When you say the arc $i-j$, do you mean go from $i$ to $j$ or to transition from one to the other?

Comment: I am sorry for this misunderstanding it is transition from $i$ to $j$, like$X_{n-1}=i\,\,and\,\,X_n=j$.

Comment: What if arc $ij$ is never visited because you end up at an absorbing state first?

Comment: Should not be a problem because Prob{N>l}=0 when l>=0 if Markov chain like you think.

Comment: @MishaLavrov In that case the distribution of this time (say $T$) would have $\mathbb P(T=0)>0$  then.